# Type error in Vue 3 SFC while set v-model on textarea

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, eslint, volar

For some reason, I start getting error in VSCode while putting v-model on a <textarea>.

Here is the error:

```
(property) TextareaHTMLAttributes.value?: string | number | string[] | undefined
  Type 'Ref<string>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my code:

```
const message = ref('');
<textarea v-model="message" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Type your ref as follows :

```js
import { TextareaHTMLAttributes } from 'vue';
....
const message = ref<TextareaHTMLAttributes['value']>('');
```